# Fetch 3d Model from IPFS then render using three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, ipfs

I don't have a snippet yet, but I can fetch data from the IPFS but still confused on how to render a 3d model on the front-end is there a documentation as it only downloads the file when trying to access the IPFS CID is there a resource or package that I can use to render?

Answer (score 1):

You want to upload and download the 3D files as `.glb` (GL binary format) so all textures stay in one file, and use a utility like [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) to load and render the file.